# VI - Paste something in the first position/character of a succession of lines

Tags: vi

I would like to yank one character and paste it in the first position of the succession of lines. For example, I need to add a "#" in the front of 7 lines of a file.

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends largely on what you're calling `vi`.  If it is really original-vi, then you could do this by

- typing <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>l</kbd> to "yank" a character starting at the cursor position, going one cell to the right.
- moving the cursor to the first line where you want to put text
- repetitively typing <kbd>0</kbd><kbd>P</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>, going through the seven lines.

In original-vi, you could only affect a range of lines using *ex* mode.
The *ex* mode of `vi` does accept a range, but the analogous command

```
:1,7P
```

would not *`put`* a *character*, but attempt to do something with *lines*.  Rather, using *ex* mode, you would do a *substitute*, e.g.,

```
:1,7s/^/X/
```

but there is no way for a *register value* (the character(s) which you *yanked*) to be used in the substitution.

Further reading:

- [ex](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/ex.html) (POSIX)
- [vi](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/vi.html) (POSIX)
- [4. EX COMMAND MODE](http://heather.cs.ucdavis.edu/~matloff/Elvis/Doc/elvisex.html) (Elvis editor)
- [5. Introducing the ex Editor](http://wwwmpa.mpa-garching.mpg.de/~gaoliang/vi/ch05_01.htm)  (from *Learning the vi Editor*)

Comment: Thank you for your answer!! I will use the first method of your answer...

Answer (score 1):

*Note: this answer works for VIM only, not for VI.*

You can yank it in a column by:

1. Starting in normal mode (not insert).
2. Go to the first row and column (where you want to insert the text).
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to enter in vertical select mode.
4. When having selected all lines in front of which you want to paste your text, press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>.
5. Now you can either

   1. paste your yanked text with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>0</kbd> (or another register).
   2. or write any text.
6. When finished, press <kbd>Esc</kbd>, and the same text will appear in all the selected lines.

---

Side note: you can also ask your Vi(m) questions on: [vi.stackexchange.com](http://vi.stackexchange.com)

Comment: That's for *vim*, which is not *vi*.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!! I think that it is a god's level of vim!! WOW!!